# Why does model=None, and how am I supposed to solve it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

I keep getting an error that says

```
runfile('C:/Users/admin/Documents/GitHub/Self-driving-Car/convo_nn.py', wdir='C:/Users/admin/Documents/GitHub/Self-driving-Car')
------------------------------
Parameters
------------------------------
data_dir             := data
test_size            := 0.2
keep_prob            := 0.5
nb_epoch             := 10
samples_per_epoch    := 20000
batch_size           := 40
save_best_only       := True
learning_rate        := 0.0001
------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\Self-driving-Car\convo_nn.py", line 233, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\Self-driving-Car\convo_nn.py", line 226, in main
    model = build_model(args)

  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\Self-driving-Car\convo_nn.py", line 128, in build_model
    Model.add(Convolution2D(24, (5, 5), padding='same', strides=(2, 2),input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'
```

Code attached below

```
def build_model(args):
    activation_relu = 'relu'
    Model = Sequential()

    #Model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x / 127.5 - 1.0, input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE))

    Model.add(Convolution2D(24, (5, 5), padding='same', strides=(2, 2),input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE))
    Model.add(Activation(activation_relu))
    Model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1, 1)))

    Model.add(Convolution2D(36, (5, 5), padding='same', strides=(2, 2)))
    Model.add(Activation(activation_relu))
    Model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1, 1)))

    Model.add(Convolution2D(48, (5, 5), padding='same', strides=(2, 2)))
    Model.add(Activation(activation_relu))
    Model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1, 1)))

    Model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', strides=(1, 1)))
    Model.add(Activation(activation_relu))
    Model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1, 1)))

    Model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', strides=(1, 1)))
    Model.add(Activation(activation_relu))
    Model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1, 1)))

    Model.add(Flatten())

    # Next, five fully connected layers
    Model.add(Dense(1164))
    Model.add(Activation("tanh"))

    Model.add(Dense(100))
    Model.add(Activation("tanh"))

    Model.add(Dense(50))
    Model.add(Activation("tanh"))

    Model.add(Dense(10))
    Model.add(Activation("tanh"))

    Model.add(Dense(nb_classes,activation="softmax"))

    Model.summary()

    return Model
```

However, if I add a clause:

```
if Model is not None:
    ...

else:
    pass
```

the code compiles successfully. Thus I could understand that model is always equalling to None. For the full code find the link attached below:

[NeuroNetwork.py](https://github.com/RoWeasley/Asphalt-9-AI/blob/main/NeuroNetwork.py)

To try this run Asphalt 9, run trainer.py to get training data. Then
run NeuroNetwork.py to build a convolutional neural network. Then run AI.py on Asphalt 9, for the AI to, hypothetically play the game. I've only coded it for TouchDrive right now.
I'm relatively new to Python, so do excuse me if it's a basic error

Use case: An Asphalt-9 AI based on previous codes...
I have made a training data extraction code and a hardware keyboard sending and receiving libraries and everything else works, except this... It's supposed to be a convolutional neural network...

Comment: Please provide [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Don't just dump the whole code. Remove unrelated parts (e.x. commented code, arguments parsing, etc.)

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong, but what’s less clear is how this ought to be indented. Don’t make us guess; please [edit] to fix this. (On the desktop version of this site, paste your program, select it, and type ctrl-K to properly format it as code.)

Comment: I have changed the question accordingly